# How do I make a app in Quickly and play a sound when a button is clicked in the app?

Tags: sound, quickly, signal

Is there anyway I can make an application in which a button made in Glade can be clicked to play a custom re-definable sound?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to connect the 'activate' signal of the button  to a handler function that then calls a library to play a sound.  For the sound playing part you can use any of the modules listed [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio)

In glade select the button then choose signals and enter a name for the function handler:
[image: Glade-SignalHandler]

Then in your python code for the window, create the function (on_iconbutton_activate in my example). Here's an example that just makes a system call to ring a bell:

```
import os
....otherstuff...

def on_iconbutton_activate(self,widget,data=None):
    os.system("/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id='bell'")
```

EDIT: To make the sound redefinable, you'll need to pull the choice from somewhere. Just use a variable to store the choice (a filename for some module or id for canberra-gtk-play), you can store the variable in something like `self.sound` and reference it in the function (since you passed `self` to it), or update the variable from some widget when the button is clicked.